# StartupScript not triggered

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, registerstartupscript

Lets me explain the situation.
I have a gridview, when I hit an add button I show a popup window and let the user enter the info. When the info is completed, the user clicks OK and a client side comprobation is made and an `e.processOnServer = isValid;` with a `true` in there, so the server event runs (`btnSubmitConfig_Click`), and at the end of this function in code behind I need to insert this startup script to make an callback in the gridview to see that is populated, while the popup remains open with a message saying `submit successful`

My startup script is:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Javascript", "aspxgridEditLog.PerformCallback(); ", true);
```

And is not fired.

Any guesses please?
Thanks

Comment: Reason you are not using `ClientScriptManager`?

Comment: Because I'm doing an AsyncPostBack on the GridView:
OnCustomCallback="aspxgridEditLog_CustomCallback" is in my gridview and is what I want to trigger. It gets the data from database and binds it again to the gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I had to insert this script in the `Parent.Page`, instead of `this` because it was trying to find the gridview in the popup, so it wasn't finding it.

Now works:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Parent.Page, Parent.Page.GetType(), "Javascript", "aspxgridEditLog.PerformCallback(); ", true);
```

Thanks for the guesses, you helped me think about what was the problem.